# Error al intentar unir vectores

Tags: c++, array

Quiero unir los vectores `vector1` y `vector2` en un solo vector `vectorUnion`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void muestraVector(int v[], int longitud);
void unionVectores(int vector1[], int longit1, int vector2[], int longit2, 
int vectorUnion[],int longit3);
int main() {

const int MAXIMOV = 5;
const int MAXIMOV1 = 5;
const int MAXIMOV2 = 6;
const int O = 11;

int vector1[MAXIMOV][MAXIMOV1] = { { 1, 3, 5, 6, 9 },{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },{ 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 },{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 },{ 10,17,25,29,32 } };
int vector2[MAXIMOV][MAXIMOV2] = { { 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 13 },{ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 },{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },{ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 },{ 1,4,6,45,46,47 } };

int vectorUnion[MAXIMOV][O];

for (int v = 0; v < MAXIMOV; v++)
{
    cout << "VECTOR1" << endl;
    muestraVector(vector1[v], MAXIMOV1);
    cout << "VECTOR2" << endl;
    muestraVector(vector2[v], MAXIMOV2);
    cout << "Union de los vectores : " << endl;
        unionVectores(vector1[v], MAXIMOV1, vector2[v], MAXIMOV2, 
vectorUnion[v], O);
        muestraVector(vectorUnion[v], O);

}

system("pause");


return 0;
}

void muestraVector(int v[], int longitud)
{
cout << "[";
if (longitud > 0)
{
    cout << v[0];
}
for (int i = 1; i < longitud; i++)
    cout << "," << v[i];
cout << "]" << endl;
}

void unionVectores(int vector1[], int longit1, int vector2[], int longit2, 
int vectorUnion[],int longit3) {

int x = 0;
int z = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (longit1 + longit2); i+2) {

    vectorUnion[i] = vector1[x];  
    x++;
}
for (int j = 1; j < (longit1 + longit2); j + 2) {

    vectorUnion[j] = vector2[z];
    z++;
}
}
```

Entonces pensé en hacer una función que me permitiera unir los dos vectores 
de manera que si por ejemplo

```
vector1 : {1,3,5,6,9}
vector2 : {2,4,6,7,8,13}
```

el vector unido seria:

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,13}
```

pero me manda un error cuando intento cambiar el valor de

```
vectorUnion[i] = vector1[x]  // se produjo una excepción:infracción de acceso de lectura.
```

Supongo que esto no se puede hacer, pero no se el porque no se puede, me podrían orientar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este bucle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (longit1 + longit2); i+2) {
  vectorUnion[i] = vector1[x];  
  x++;
}
```

Tenemos que tanto `i` como `x` se moverán en el rango (0,10). `vectorUnion[i]` no te va a dar problemas porque `vectorUnion` admite 11 enteros, pero `vector1` es un vector de tan solo 5 elementos y eso implica que ese bucle realiza 6 lecturas fuera de la memoria de `vector1`.

Con el bucle que le precede sucede exactamente lo mismo y los Sistemas Operativos modernos tienen la mala costumbre de prevenir que un proceso acceda a memoria que no le pertenece por eso de prevenir la corrupción de la memoria de otras aplicaciones y la forma que tiene de evitar que esto suceda es matando el proceso que accede a la memoria... en este caso tu aplicación.

La solución es tan sencilla como reorganizar esos bucles:

- El primer bucle solo puede iterar en el rango 0..4
- El segundo bucle iterará en el rango 0..5.
- El índice a `vectorUnion` debe estar compartido por ambos bucles:

Algo así:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<longit1; ++i )
  vectorUnion[i] = vector1[i];

for(int x=0; x<longit2; ++x, ++i )
  vectorUnion[i] = vector2[x];
```

O, si prefieres con punteros:

```
int* ptr = vectorUnion;
for(int i=0; i<longit1; ++i, ++ptr )
  *ptr = vector1[i];

for(int i=0; i<longit2; ++i, ++ptr )
  *ptr = vector2[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Dado que estás trabajando con formaciones<sup>1</sup> de tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación, te aconsejaría usar funciones plantilla para realizar la copia, una función de unir vectores podría tener este aspecto:

```
template <typename tipo, std::size_t tamanyo_a, std::size_t tamanyo_b>
void unir_vectores(tipo (&vector_a)[tamanyo_a], tipo (&vector_b)[tamanyo_b], tipo (&destino)[tamanyo_a + tamanyo_b])
{
    auto iterador = std::copy(std::begin(vector_a), std::end(vector_a), std::begin(destino));
    std::copy(std::begin(vector_b), std::end(vector_b), iterador);
}
```

La ventaja de esta aproximación es que obtiene el tamaño de las formaciones<sup>1</sup> en tiempo de compilación y comprueba que el tipo coincida antes de hacer la unión y no te permitirá unir dos formaciones<sup>1</sup> sobre una tercera que no coincida con el tamaño de la suma del tamaño de las dos anteriores, por ejemplo, esto fallaría:

```
int a[10]{}, b[11]{}, c[12]{};
unir_vectores(a, b, c); // Error, espera que c tenga tamanyo 21
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Cl5eiWHTh3fUHSdU)</kbd>.

---

1. También conocidas como arreglos o en inglés: arrays.